# Align the center of the text with the center of its container in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I want to align centers of two objects in a `Row` container: a `Box` (shaped as a circle) and a `Text`.

```
@Composable
fun AlignTest(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
  Row(
    verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
  ) {
    Box(
      modifier = modifier
        .padding(end = 8.dp)
        .size(10.dp)
        .background(
          color = Color.Red, shape = CircleShape
        )
        .border(
          width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black, shape = CircleShape
        )
    )
  
    Text(
      text = "Text",
      fontSize = 100.sp
    )
  }
}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

(Blue line is added by me)

As you can see, the center of the `Box` object is aligned with the center of the `Row`, but the center of the `Text` is not. There's more free space on the top of the `Text` than on the bottom.

I tried adding `modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)` to the `Text`, but that didn't help. Also tried putting the `Text` in another `Box`, filling the max height, but that also didn't help.

I would like the center of `Text` object to be aligned with the center of the `Row`, and therefore, with the center of the `Box` object.

Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I tried a [method](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b) suggested by @Abhimanyu in the comments:

```
  Text(
    modifier = modifier.background(Color.LightGray),
    style = LocalTextStyle.current.merge(
      TextStyle(
        lineHeight = 100.sp,
        platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
          includeFontPadding = false
        ),
        lineHeightStyle = LineHeightStyle(
          alignment = LineHeightStyle.Alignment.Center,
          trim = LineHeightStyle.Trim.None
        )
      )
    ),
    text = "Text",
    fontSize = 100.sp
  )
```

It improved the situation, but didn't fully fixed it:

[image]
[image]

Only chanding the `includeFontPadding` flag affects the font padding. Changing `LineHeightStyle.Alignment`, `LineHeightStyle.Trim` and `lineHeight` has no effect.

Comment: This may be because of the font padding. Can you add a color background to the `Text` composable and see?

Comment: @Abhimanyu, it's a standard Material3 `Text` component. Even if there's some internal font padding, I still would like to be able to align centers. Here's the [background fill](https://imgur.com/UZ05bep).

Comment: As you can see in the image you have shared, the grey is the `Text` composable size. So, it is centered within the `Row`.

Comment: The issue is in Font Padding.

Comment: For info on font padding - https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/fixing-font-padding-in-compose-text-768cd232425b

Comment: What is the Compose version you are using?

Comment: @Abhimanyu I'm using Compose 1.4.8. Thanks for the article.

Comment: Have you tried giving your row a size? E.g. ```modifier.fillMaxWidth.height(200.dp)```?

Comment: @CodePoet, yes, but it doesn't affect the font padding.

Answer (score 0):

This is not exact solution but you can try:

```
Text(modifier = modifier.background(Color.LightGray),
        style = LocalTextStyle.current.merge(
            TextStyle(
                platformStyle = PlatformTextStyle(
                    includeFontPadding = false
                ),
                baselineShift = BaselineShift(
                    -0.04f
                )
            )
        ),
        text = "TEXT",
        fontSize = 100.sp
    )
```

Comment: Text is centered differently for `Text` and `TEXT`. Your `baselineShift` value is only somewhat correct for the `TEXT`, but not the `Text`. Also if `fontSize` changes from `100.sp`, it also won't be correct (for example, when user changes the font size preference).